# How to disable autocorrect for only one application in OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications, autocorrect

I know there is an option to disable autocorrect for all applications, but how do I disable autocorrect for only one application?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turn off Autocorrect per Application

You can  do this in "Edit" menu for that Application under "Spelling and Grammar" and disable "Check Spelling While Typing".

Comment: I didn't think it was possible, but you have shed the light. Thank you.

Comment: sorry what is the Applications edit menu?

Answer (score 4):

Update for 2022 and some apps like and FB messenger where the "Edit" menu doesn't have the sought option:

`Left-click where you would type > Spelling and Grammar > Correct Spelling Automatically`

Answer (score 3):

*I want to expand on @Grizzwald's answer as that sadly won't always work.*

---

**IF** "Correct Spelling Automatically" is **grayed out** for your Application (which was the case for me using the Todoist app).

- *Found here:* `Edit->Spelling and Grammer->Correct Spelling Automatically`

**THEN** you'll (unfortunately) need to turn this off for all Applications under:

- `System Preferences->Keyboard->Text->Correct Spelling Automatically`

Comment: This was disabled (grayed out) for the application I was using since I wasn't centered on a text input field. Once I was in "writing mode" it became available.